# YII2 : upload file in actionCreate

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2-advanced-app

my Model code is :

```
  [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
```

in the form i added this :

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
```

in my controller Action create :

```
{
    $model = new items();

   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
   
    $model->file=UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');  
    $ImageName=$model->id;
    $model->file->saveAs( $ImageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );


    $model->store_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->store_id ;
    
    $model->save() ;
   
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

the problem i got is :

> Bad Request (#400)
>
> Missing required parameters: id

Nothing uploaded and there is no row create in the database .

Comment: Your function definition is `public function actionCreate($id)`, right?

Comment: That's true ... and I forget to mention that I've create `public file;` in my model

Comment: Sorry  , I didn't focus That you wrote $id and the action create .. i use `public function actionCreate() { code here }`

Comment: The, the field `id` of your model is missing. What happens if you save it without validation: `$model->save(false)`?

Comment: It works .. but the image name was empty

Comment: There you have your problem, you are not getting the `id` properly. Focus on that